# How to get input type by element name

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Is there any way to get type of input by having element name?

```
<form name="formQuestionnaire">
    <input name="age" type="radio" id="age-1" />
    <input name="age" type="radio" id="age-2" />
</form>

document.forms['formQuestionnaire'].elements['age']
```

return radio / checkbox / text

Comment: Fire up the console in Chrome (press F12, click on console) and start typing things like `document.forms` and you'll see that you can explore the JavaScript DOM API. It's a pretty good way to learn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
var x = document.forms['formQuestionnaire'].elements['age'];
x = x.length ? x[0] : x;
alert(x.type)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/EMNDR/5/)

Comment: Thank you but if you have more than two element it wont work!

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="age" name="age" type="radio" />

...
var input = document.getElementById('age');
alert(input.type);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get `type` property:

```
var type = document.forms["formQuestionnaire"].elements["age"].type;
```

It is somewhat better than using `getAttribute("type")`, since in case of non defined `type` *attribute* (default is `text`) the latter gives `null`, while `type` *property* returns `text`, as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

If you want more than one element.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EMNDR/23/)

```js
var x = document.forms['formQuestionnaire'].elements['age'];

for(var i=0;i< x.length;i++){
    
var u = x.length ? x[i] : x;
    
    alert(u.type);
    
}
```

```html
<form name="formQuestionnaire">
    <input name="age" type="radio" id="age-1" />
    <input name="age" type="checkbox" id="age-2" />
</form>
```